# Stochastic differential equation without diffusion

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following SDE

$X_t=\int_0^t \sqrt{1+B_s^2}\cdot dB_s$ or

$dX_t=\sqrt{1+B_t^2}\cdot dB_t$

If I define the stochastic variable $Y_t=X_t^2$.

How can I determine the Ito equation that would satisfy $Y_t$?

Can I apply Ito's lemma?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can apply Itô's lemma... give it a try!

Comment: After applying Ito's lemma, I found that $dY_t=(1+B_t^2)dt+2X_t*sqrt(1+B_t^2)*dB_t$.   Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.